# Python - How to exit while loop with command line input() by pressing Esc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am working on windows OS. My application is getting name text from command prompt using input() method in while loop. I want to exit while loop by pressing Esc key but input() is not recognizing Esc key. How to handle both input() method and Esc key press in while loop in Python

```
def get_name_from_user():
    result = False
    while True:
        name = input("Enter the name:")
        if validate_name(name):
            return True
        else:
            print("Name allows only alpha numeric characters.")
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead check for an empty string? Most CLI tools that take multiple inputs will check for an empty string to indicate that the user is finished with input.

```
def get_name_from_user():
    result = False
    while True:
        name = input("Enter the name:")
        if name == "":
            break

        if validate_name(name):
            return True
        else:
            print("Name allows only alpha numeric characters.")
    return result
```

Comment: My functionality is registering user. I  have fields name, age, dob, If I  press Esc key it should skip getting command prompt input for other fields age, dob , email, mobile no. If Some fields are optional, how to differentiate Enter key press is for accepting optional field with empty value or exiting from  the registration operation itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using msvcrt. On Windows, this module allows users to input individual keystrokes.

```
import msvcrt

def get_name_from_user():
    result = False
    while True:
        name = ""
        while True:
            char = msvcrt.getch()
            if char == chr(13): # enter key
                break
            elif char == chr(27): # escape key
                return result
            else:
                name += char
        if validate_name(name):
            return True
        else:
            print("Name allows only alpha numeric characters.")
    return result
```

Alternatively tkinter bind may help but that is probably not a good idea because of the modifications you'll need to make.

Comment: I had to use something similar once when designing a brainfuck IDE in python (bad choice of language, I was and still am a beginner) but was on Mac instead of Windows so eventually had to give up :(